# What is the simplest way to remove, then return, one column from a CSV file?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I often need to run various scripts which edit the data inside a CSV file, but restricted to only a particular column within that file. Redesigning all of the scripts so that they only manipulate a particular column is sometimes complicated. I think the simplest method is to output the particular column to a temporary file, such as `temp.csv`, run the scripts on `temp.csv`, then place this edited data back into the same column in the CSV file.

I know that I can retrieve just the data from a particular column of a CSV file using this:

```
awk -F@ '{print $3}' file.csv >> temp.csv
```

After editing `temp.csv` with the scripts, what is the simplest way to return this data back to the same column in the CSV file?

Comment: You can use paste command, but what exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to take out column 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `$3` in place. E.g.:

```
awk -F@ 'BEGIN { OFS= FS }
         { # do whatever with $3, like
           $3 += 2
           $3 = $3 "appended text"
           # and so on, then finally
           print $0
         }' INPUT.CSV > OUTPUT.CSV
```